# Magento 2.4.2 Customer Login Not Working

Tags: magento2, frontend

When a customer tries to login to the front end website, they enter their user name and password and then when they click to login, it appears to be successful but they were not logged in. This is a fairly recent issue and I'm not sure what caused it. One possibility is that it's related to an update to my theme.

Comment: Any updates about this? I'm having the same problem (also in Luma, so not theme related)

Comment: This article should help towards this https://www.sitepoint.com/fix-magento-login-issues-cookies-sessions/ This is based on Magento 1 but is applicable for Magento 2, you just need to be wary about it.

Comment: Try again after cleaning your browser cookies

Comment: It shouldn't be related to your theme but if customers return after a change or update with cookies from pre-change sometimes things can go weird.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

In my Magento 2.4.6-p2 I could not log in as frontend user, but I could see that its logged in as a user in admin area (Customers > Now online).
It turned out, in **Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Setting** -> "Cookie Domain" field was wrong.

In first sight it was ok, something like "us.blabla.localhost", real localhost domain that I was using for local development. But it didn't work. So I changed it to this one ".blabla.localhost". Without first part of domain "us" but with the dot at the start. And after that it started working )

Hope it will help someone

Comment: Upvoted, this sounds specifically like a cookie domain issue. My local installation had the same problem because the Cookie domain was still set to the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check you configurations if properly set. Check the exepection log, system log and debug log to see if any error is there which is redirecting user back to login page.